# Unlocked Huawei E303 vs Locked Huawei E303

Tags: usb-modem

Huawei E303 is a well known and widely used mobile broadband device (USB Modem / Data card), it is available in two types: Hi-link and Normal.

I have that modem and it works fine. I was searching on the internet for information about it when I come across unlocking the Huawei E303.

Are there any hidden features on my device that can be unlocked?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only advantage to unlocking your Huawei E303—and the only reason to unlock it—is to circumvent paying for it’s use. There are no “hidden” features with unlocking it.

If this is something you’re interested in, I suggest you do more research on your own. This website will most likely not give you the answer you seek on how to unlock the device to keep you from paying your bill.

Comment: recently i downloaded new update of E303 from Huawei site and it looks like flashed my USB and added new update software setup which is different from the setup provided and come within e303 from my provider ! .... so i still not understand that unlock concept because inside that E303 there is Sim , i put that sim in mobile and activate 3G package and then put in e303 and i use it because their Pc software have no dial function due to which i cant activate 3G package from software directly ! .... to me it's just PC 3G Modem .. so Unlocking mean free internet no paying or what ...

Comment: Well, when I did a Google search, #1 shows part of you question ripped from ModemUnlock.com but aside from that, if you scroll further down the results page, you'll get all the information you need on how and why (which is to attempt to circumvent paying for the service as I said in my answer.)